# Sending cookies between express.js and react

Tags: reactjs, express, google-chrome, cookies, cors

from my server my code is:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const port = 5656;
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
//Routers
const registerRouter = require('./routers/register.js')
const loginRouter = require('./routers/login.js')


//MiddleWare
app.use(cors({credentials:true ,origin:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use('/register', registerRouter)
app.use('/login', loginRouter)




app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('working')
})

app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`server is listening on port ${port}`) });
```

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()
const con = require('../db/dbConnection.js')

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    if (email && password) {
        console.log(email, password)
        con.query('select * from users where email = ?', [email], (err, result) => {
            if (!err) {
                if (result[0].password == password) {
                    console.log(result[0])
                    res.cookie('ID', result[0].id, { maxAge: 172800 * 1000 / 2 })
                    res.send(result[0])
                } else {
                    res.send({ msg: 'Wrong password' })
                }
            } else {
                res.send({ msg: err })
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        res.send({ msg: "plases insert email and password" })
    }
})

module.exports = router
```

from my client side with react, my code is:

```
    let onLogin = () => {
        fetch('http://localhost:5656/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'omit',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
 
    }
```

whenever I am sending the request from react server which is localhost:3000, I am getting an error from chrome saying "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute",
and when I am using PostMan the cookie is delivered perfectly.

i tried to change the code adding sameSite settings but it does not work.

any chance you know what to do?

thank you in advance.

Comment: A necessary condition for browsers to honour the `Set-Cookie` header in a cross-origin response is that the request be credentialed. Accordingly, you should specify `credentials: 'include'` instead of `credentials: 'omit'`.

Comment: Also, never ever configure CORS like this: `cors({credentials:true ,origin:true})`. It effectively voids the Same-Origin Policy's restrictions on network access and exposes your users to attacks coming from any Web origins.

Comment: @jub0bs hey there man, thank you for the reply! I actually tried credentials: “include” but it didn’t work either. I have changed it after seeing it on some explanation.